# Why are my typolinks t3: not replaced if I fetch them with CONTENT?

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typolink

I have Typoscript like this:

```
lib.rccProcessTexts = CONTENT
lib.rccProcessTexts {

    table = tt_content
    select {
        pidInList = {$rcc.ids.pidRccProcessTexts}
    }

    renderObj = COA
    renderObj {
       10 = TEXT

       # The field tt_content.bodytext holds the content text.
       10.stdWrap.field = bodytext

       10.stdWrap.wrap = <div data-phase-id="{field:colPos}">|</div>
       10.insertData = 1
 }

wrap = <div class="hidden" data-process-texts>|</div>
}
```

So this Typoscript fetches content from tt_content. Any typolinks (`t3://...`) are not replaced by real links (like `https://www.example.com/go/to/page`).

How can I make TYPO3 create real links?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 2 possibilities.

1. is documented here: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/main/en-us/ContentObjects/Text/Index.html

It is to add this parseFunc to the TEXT object:

```
10.stdWrap.parseFunc < lib.parseFunc_RTE
```

This will cause the text to be parsed as usual.

So finally:

```
...
...
renderObj = COA
    renderObj {
       10 = TEXT

       # The field tt_content.bodytext holds the content text.
       10.stdWrap.field = bodytext

       10.stdWrap.wrap = <div data-phase-id="{field:colPos}">|</div>
       10.insertData = 1
       10.stdWrap.parseFunc < lib.parseFunc_RTE
 }
 ...
```

2. The second is to write a userfunc with PHP.

`10.stdWrap.parseFunc.userFunc = My\Way\To\MyClass.php->doSomething()`

Then just add Class.php with doSomething() to the Classes/UserFunc folder. The class is like so:

```
<?php
namespace My\Way\To;

class MyClass
{
  /**
   * @var \TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\ContentObject\ContentObjectRenderer
   */
  public $cObj;


/**
    *
    * @param  string When custom methods are used for data processing (like in stdWrap functions), the $content variable will hold the value to be processed. When methods are meant to just return some generated content (like in USER and USER_INT objects), this variable is empty.
    * @param  array  TypoScript properties passed to this method.
    * @return string The input string reversed. If the TypoScript property "uppercase" was set, it will also be in uppercase. May also be linked.
    */
    public function doSomething(string $content, array $conf): string 
    {
       // Have fun
    }


}
```

Comment: I would definitely go for the first option.